# Deserialize Kafka AVRO messages using Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-beam, dataflow

The main goal is the aggregate two Kafka topics, one compacted slow moving data and the other fast moving data which is received every second.

I have been able to consume messages in simple scenarios such as a KV (Long,String) using something like:

```
PCollection<KV<Long,String>> input = p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, 
String>read()
.withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
.withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
  
PCollection<String> output = input.apply(Values.<String>create());
```

But this doesn’t seem to be the approach when you need to deserialize from AVRO. I have a KV(STRING, AVRO) which I need to consume.

I attempted generating the Java Classes from the AVRO schema and then including them in the “apply” for example:

```
PCollection<MyClass> output = input.apply(Values.<MyClass>create());
```

But this didn’t seem to be the correct approach.

Is there any documentation/examples anyone could point me to, so I could get an understanding as to how you would work with Kafka AVRO and Beam?

I have updated my code:

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<KV<Long, Myclass>> input = p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
            .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(Myclass.class))
    );

    p.run();

}
}
```

---

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.DefaultCoder;

@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class Myclass{
String name;
String age;

Myclass(){}
Myclass(String n, String a) {
    this.name= n;
    this.age= a;
}
}
```

But i now get the following error

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Class < io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer > cannot be converted to java.lang.Class < ? extends org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer < java.lang.String > >
```

I must be importing the incorrect serializers?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. Found the solution in this mail-archives.
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/beam-user/201710.mbox/%3CCAMsy_NiVrT_9_xfxOtK1inHxb=x_yAdBcBN+4aquu_hn0GJ0nA@mail.gmail.com%3E

In your case, you need to defined your own `Deserializer<MyClass>`, which can extend from `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` like as follows.

```
public class MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer extends
  AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer implements Deserializer<MyClass> {
  
  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
      configure(new KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig(configs));
  }

  @Override
  public MyClass deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
      return (MyClass) this.deserialize(bytes);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {} }
```

Then specify your *KafkaAvroDeserializer* as ValueDeserializer.

```
p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, MyClass>read()
 .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
 .withValueDeserializer(MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer.class) );
```

Comment: I've found that extending from `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` doesn't matter here if you just implement the interface the make an inner field for a concrete instance of `KafkaAvroDeserializer` and delegate to it. In any case, you should be able to remove the configure and close method overrides if you extend from `KafkaAvroDeserialzer` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use KafkaAvroDeserializer as following:

```
PCollection<KV<Long,MyClass>> input = p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
.withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
  .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(MyClass.class))
```

Where **MyClass** is the POJO class generated Avro Schema.

Make sure your POJO class has annotation AvroCoder as in below example :

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
   public class MyClass{
      String name;
      String age;

      MyClass(){}
      MyClass(String n, String a) {
         this.name= n;
         this.age= a;
      }
  }
```

Comment: If the KafkaAvroDeserializer.class from io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer? Thats what i'm currently using, but it gives me an error as its expecting a deserializer from org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

Comment: Yes, its from Confluent package. What error do you get? Can you paste the error stack trace?

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear, i get a compilation error, which is:     Error:(47, 69) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer<my_test_class>>. 

AvroCode is from org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder

Comment: You have to annotate your POJO class with AvroCoder(as given in answer). Have you done that?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, i have updated my post with your suggested changes. But i still get the same error, i have included my imports as i'm assuming it's has something to do with them.

Comment: I am facing the same error. This solution does not work. I got this error: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/01087872/Documents/fr-det-avro-sample/src/main/java/examples/MyClassConsumer.java:[19,17] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints java.lang.Object,examples.MyClass

Comment: Avro POJO classes are usually generated from `avro-maven-plugin` for example. How to add annotations to them?

Answer (score 0):

Yohei's answer is good, but I also found this to work

```java
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer;

...

public static class CustomKafkaAvroDeserializer extends SpecificAvroDeserializer<MyCustomClass> {}

...
.withValueDeserializerAndCoder(CustomKafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(MyCustomClass.class))
...
```

where `MyCustomClass` is code gen'd with Avro tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today, and came across the following example which resolved it for me.

https://github.com/andrewrjones/debezium-kafka-beam-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andrewjones/KafkaAvroConsumerExample.java

the missing piece for me was (Class)KafkaAvroDeserializer

```
KafkaIO.<String, MyClass>read()
        .withBootstrapServers("kafka:9092")
        .withTopic("dbserver1.inventory.customers")
        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
        .withValueDeserializerAndCoder((Class)KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(MyClass.class))
```

Comment: `.class` should already return a Class object, so the cast doesn't seem necessary...

Answer (score -1):

Change `KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()` to `KafkaIO.<Long, Object>read()`.

If you look into the implementation of `KafkaAvroDeserializer`, it implements `Deserializer<Object>`:

`public class KafkaAvroDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object>`

Comment: I am facing the same error and this also does not fix the issue. I got this error: Compilation failure [ERROR] /Users/01087872/Documents/fr-det-avro-sample/src/main/java/examples/MyClassConsumer.java:[19,17] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints java.lang.Object,examples.MyClass