# Apache Beam Publish Kafka Message with KafkaIO and KafkaAvroSerialization for GenericRecord

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, beam

I am new to Beam and I don't know how can I publish custom message using KafkaIO.write.
I have to use KafkaAvroSerializer.class as the value serializer.

```
public void publish(CustomObject customObj) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);


  PCollection<KafkaRecord<Long, GenericRecord>> response = 
  p.apply(Create.of(customObj))
     .apply(KafkaIO.<Long, GenericRecord>write()
            .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .withTopic("myTopic")
            .withKeySerializer(LongDeserializer.class)
            .withValueSerializer(KafkaAvroSerializer.class)

            .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("auto.offset.reset", (Object)"earliest"))

           
    );
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

Comment: Is this example useful? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Java/src/main/java/kafka/WriteKafka.java

Comment: Several examples with Long or String as key/value serializers exist. but my question is how to use the KafkaAvroSerializer class here.

Comment: Not sure what error you got. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755668/deserialize-kafka-avro-messages-using-apache-beam has more information about this.